# Align image in image view right and center vertical

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, scaling

Let's say i have an ImageView with this aspect ratio

```
#####
#####
#####
```

I want to be able to fit images in it that can have different aspect ratios.

If an Image has this ratio

```
00
00
00
```

I want it to be

```
###00
###00
###00
```

So android:scaleType="fitEnd" would work

But if I have an image with a ratio of

```
00000
```

I want it to be

```
#####
00000
#####
```

so here android:scaleType="fitCenter" is needed.

Is there a way to combine this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use two `scaleTypes` in the same attribute. You may need to wait for the image to be loaded and then decide what `scaleType` use with `imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER)` or so.